# Execute org-mode source blocks without security confirmation

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, security

I only want to turn off the warnings for certain source block languages.

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, only how to turn off the confirmation requests for all languages:

```
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
```

This is a super easy question for someone who knows e-lisp. It should be included with the documentation in my opinion, but there is only one language in [the example](http://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html).

How can I extend this to include more languages?

```
(defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
            (not (string= lang "ditaa")))  ; don't ask for ditaa
          (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't try it: `(member* "python" '("ditaa" "python") :test 'string=)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I personally don't use babel much, going from the example, this should simply be:

```el
(defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
  (not (member lang '("C" "clojure" "sh"))))

(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```

Where `C`, `clojure` and `sh` should be replaced by the languages you don't want the confirmation for.

Comment: Seems to be working fine, thanks!  You need an extra bracket in there after `... "sh")))`

Comment: Oops, Thanks! That always seems to happen when I don't have paredit-mode on...